# 'Undefined control sequence' error tabular tabitem

Tags: tables, errors

Why am I getting this error?

I have a list of items in the center of my page. This does the job, however, i get an error.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      \textbf{Diagnosekoder:} \\
      \tabitem K74 - Iskmisk hjertesygdom med angina pectoris \\
      \tabitem K76 - Iskmisk hjertesygdom uden angina pectoris \\
      \tabitem Akut myokardieinfarkt
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Have you defined `\tabitem` above this code? This is not a standard command, so you have to define it or load a package that does it.

Comment: If you saw any documentation that suggested  using a command called `\tabitem` it should have also said how to define it.

Comment: Yes thank you, the definition is what I've missed. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tabitem) to see howdifferent people are defining a command with that name.